# How can I query the system rc path set at compile time with -DSYS_BASHRC=?

Tags: bash, configuration

How do I query the compile-time options of bash on a given system?

The system rc path for bash differs across systems. Sometimes it is `/etc/bash.bashrc` and sometimes it is `/etc/bashrc`. How can I detect this programmatically?

I know I can list options in a shell with:

```
set -o
```

or

```
shopt
```

Comment: (and sometimes it isn't anything at all ... at least on macOS, both the built-in and homebrew bash don't source `/etc/bashrc` unless told to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, [Bash source code](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/shell.c) doesn't differentiate between `SYS_BASHRC` and other included rc files after compilation.  In addition, `SYS_BASHRC` could be undefined, and the resulting binary wouldn't use a system rc at all.

All the files used by a process can be found out by `strace`, however.  Bash includes rc files only if it is run interactively, so:

```
echo | strace -e openat -o tmp.log bash -i 2>/dev/null
```

The resulting file `tmp.log` will contain the information wanted:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/bash.bashrc", O_RDONLY) = 3
```

Unfortunately, it will also contain large numbers of lines e.g. for libraries (and the redirection to /dev/null).  I'm not sure how to select the correct line in every case.  But in practice I think it will most probably be the first non-library in `/etc/`:

```
grep -v O_CLOEXEC tmp.log | grep \"/etc | head -n 1 | sed -e 's/.*"\(.*\)".*/\1/'
```

Comment: You can tell bash to log the files: `PS4='$(echo "${BASH_SOURCE}" >> tmp.log)' bash -ixc true 2>/dev/null`, followed by `awk '!a[$0]++' tmp.log`

Comment: You're right, that's a neater solution.  Though I'd use `sort -u` (or just `head -n 1`) instead of `awk` :)